# Access File saved in Amazon EBS volume using MVC4 Application

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-ebs

Thanks in advance.

I need to access some **set of files** saved in a **Amazon EBS volume** which is applied to the **AWS Server Instance** using my **ASP.Net MVC4 Application** which is deployed on the **same instance** using **IIS 7**.

Regards,

Manik

Comment: I guess, amazon must be providing a unique id/name for your particular subscription/server so that you can access it using your code like windows azure storage.

Comment: Is the EBS Drive mounted on the Windows VM? If so, it is just normal file system access.